# A foto do meu perfil foi removida

Tags: suporte, bug, status-pronto, perfil

Por algum motivo a foto do meu perfil desapareceu, alguém esta com este mesmo problema no seu perfil, ou aconteceu apenas com o meu?

Testei em vários navegadores e até na guia anônima.

Neste momento eu não posso testar em outra maquina, então deixarei o link do meu perfil, quem sabe esta acontecendo apenas na minha maquina.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74441/wictor-chaves

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vi vários utilizadores com essa imagem como default, pensava que tinha sido propositado, se você for à lista de usuários vê vários assim também

Comment: Eu também reparei isso, a principio achei que era a minha maquina, mas depois de testar em outros navegadores, então comecei suspeitar se existia algum motivo.

Comment: Deve ser algum problema com a API do facebook, pois a foto que você usava é a que está vinculada ao seu perfil do face

Comment: O problema está em todos os sites da rede stack exchange, veja: [What happened to Stack Overflow's Facebook image?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309231/229289)

Comment: Pra cada problema que o Facebook tenta resolver pra ñ ficar mal na fita está causando outros.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/2054375031451090/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49917726/retrieving-default-image-all-url-profile-picture-from-facebook-graph-api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sua foto está de volta. As fotos dos demais usuários que vi com o mesmo problema também. Então está resolvido.

O problema ocorreu porque a sua foto vem do facebook e ocorreu um problema com a integração do facebook com o Stack Overflow, uma vez que o facebook está fazendo alterações em suas APIs para reforçar a segurança.